# Updating multiple QImages on QML::Image view displays only the last one sent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qimage, qtquickcontrols

I have [Image](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-image.html) qml component to display [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html)s. Following is the `QML` code for it.

**Code:**

```
Item {

    Image {
       id: my_qimage_viewer
       anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Connections {
        target: qimage_selector_cpp_backend
        onQImageDisplayRequested: {
            my_qimage_viewer.source = next_qimage_source
            console.log("New qimage sent for display is : " + my_qimage_viewer.source)
        }
    }

}
```

**What is working:**
I have a C++ class using [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) to supply `QImage`s with different IDs every time.

This technique **basically works if** I update single `QImage`s on selection of some button by user. I can generate a `QImage` on the fly & update it on `my_qimage_viewer`. Also able to display multiple different images on demand from user. This proves that my technique using `QQuickImageProvider` is basically working.

**What is not working**
**But**, here is where the problem arises. when I send **many** `QImage`s subsequently, like 50-60 of them all in a for loop, then it does not display all but *only displays the last one sent for update* !

My objective here is to try play 50-60 `QImage`s with some millis gap in between to **make them appear like a video/animation**. Is it that the [Image](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-image.html) component is not made for such kind of use? Or is it that I am doing some mistake?

**Question:**
May be I should wait for each `QImage` to be display complete before updating the next? How can I do that if that is whats missing?

Is there an example of an app using [Image](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-image.html) to display multiple `QImage`s making it appear like a video or animation?

Comment: The answer depends on when you want to update the images, or do you want them to be only consecutive ?, that is, there is only the delay to load the image or is doing a construction and / or processing of the image

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to update all the images consecutively. Yes. there will be delay in construction of the image. But before trying with processed `QImage`s, I firstly decided to try out plain simple `QImage`s created on the fly. This is firstly to prove the framework actually works. Is there a standard example of updating multiple `QImage`s on to a [QML::Image](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-image.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a `for-loop` you do not give time to show and update the images, you should give a little time between each image.

Assuming that the acquisition time of the image is less than a certain value, for example less than 1/60 seconds we could use a `NumberAnimation` setting in an appropriate step:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Image {
        property int number
        id: name
        source: "image://numbers/"+number

        NumberAnimation on number {
            from:0
            to: 60
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
}
```

**imageprovider.h**

```
#ifndef IMAGEPROVIDER_H
#define IMAGEPROVIDER_H

#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTime>

class ImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    ImageProvider():QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image){
        qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());
    }
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize){
        int width = 100;
        int height = 50;
        if (size)
            *size = QSize(width, height);
        QImage img(requestedSize.width() > 0 ? requestedSize.width() : width,
               requestedSize.height() > 0 ? requestedSize.height() : height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
        img.fill(QColor(qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256, qrand() % 256));
        QPainter painter(&img);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        painter.drawText(QRectF(QPointF(0, 0), img.size()),  Qt::AlignCenter,
                         QTime::currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss.z")+" "+id);
        painter.end();
        return img;
    }
};

#endif // IMAGEPROVIDER_H
```

A complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47962257)

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer. this was really helpful for me to  understand this way of using `QtQuickImageProvider` in case of multiple QImages